# UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\u20a9' in position 90: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I'm a python beginner.

I'm trying to crawl google play store and export to csv file.
But I got a error message.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\u20a9' in position 90: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Here is my source code.

When I command print, it works.
But it shows error message when exporting to csv file

please help me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import codecs
import json
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import csv
import os


req = 'https://play.google.com/store/search?q=hana&c=apps&num=300'



response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)


#app_link  = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'title'})
#app_url = app_link.get('href')





for div in soup.findAll( 'div', {'class' : 'details'} ):
    title = div.find( 'a', {'class':'title'} )
    #print(title.get('href')) 
    app_url = title.get('href')

    app_details={}


    g_app_url = 'https://play.google.com' + app_url

    app_response = urllib.request.urlopen(g_app_url)
    app_page = app_response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(app_page)
    #print(soup)


    #print( g_app_url )
    title_div = soup.find( 'div', {'class':'document-title'} )
    app_details['title'] = title_div.find( 'div' ).get_text().strip()

    subtitle = soup.find( 'a', {'class' : 'document-subtitle primary'} )
    app_details['developer'] = subtitle.get_text().strip()
    app_details['developer_link'] = subtitle.get( 'href' ).strip()

    price_buy_span = soup.find( 'span', {'class' : 'price buy'} )
    price = price_buy_span.find_all( 'span' )[-1].get_text().strip()
    price = price[:-4].strip() if price != 'Install' else 'Free' 
    app_details['price'] = price

    rating_value_meta = soup.find( 'meta', {'itemprop' : 'ratingValue'} )
    app_details['rating'] = rating_value_meta.get( 'content' ).strip()

    reviewers_count_meta = soup.find( 'meta', {'itemprop' : 'ratingCount'} )
    app_details['reviewers'] = reviewers_count_meta.get( 'content' ).strip()

    num_downloads_div = soup.find( 'div', {'itemprop' : 'numDownloads'} )
    if num_downloads_div: app_details['downloads'] = num_downloads_div.get_text().strip()

    date_published_div = soup.find( 'div', {'itemprop' : 'datePublished'} )
    app_details['date_published'] = date_published_div.get_text().strip()

    operating_systems_div = soup.find( 'div', {'itemprop' : 'operatingSystems'} )
    app_details['operating_system'] = operating_systems_div.get_text().strip()

    content_rating_div = soup.find( 'div', {'itemprop' : 'contentRating'} )
    app_details['content_rating'] = content_rating_div.get_text().strip()

    category_span = soup.find( 'span', {'itemprop' : 'genre'} )
    app_details['category'] = category_span.get_text()
    #print(app_details)


    with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, app_details.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(app_details)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3 opens text files in the locale default encoding; if that encoding cannot handle the Unicode values you are trying to write to it, pick a different codec:

```
with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
```

That'd encode any unicode strings to UTF-8 instead, an encoding which can handle all of the Unicode standard.

Note that the `csv` module recommends you open files using `newline=''` to prevent newline translation.

You also need to open the file just *once*, outside of the `for` loop:

```
with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    fields = ('title', 'developer', 'developer_link', 'price', 'rating', 'reviewers',
              'downloads', 'date_published', 'operating_system', 'content_rating',
              'category')
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, )
    w.writeheader()

    for div in soup.findAll( 'div', {'class' : 'details'} ):
        #
        # build app_details
        #

        w.writerow(app_details)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have one more question for csv result. I tried the code and opened 'result.csv' file. And I found there is just one row which is last loop result. Can you explain why it stores the last loop result??

Comment: @user3172987: You are re-opening the `csv` file *every loop iteration*, which clears the file and starts a-new. Each iteration. Move opening the file *out* of the loop (including creating the `DictWriter()` object and calling `w.writeheader()`) and only call `w.writerow()` in the loop.

Comment: @user3172987: Done; give `DictWriter()` a list of keys you want to write away first.